# Error using decltype

Tags: c++, c++11

I am a beginner in C++ and trying to use `decltype`. In this code, use 1 is fine. `x` will be an int*. However, I have question about use 2. Dereferencing (`*`) pointer should give int. But seems it is `int &` reference. I am confused here. Can anyone explain?

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int i=5, *p=&i;
    decltype(p) x; //use 1
    decltype(*p) x; //use 2

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Dereferencing (*) pointer should give int

Not just any old `int`, it actually gives an lvalue. You can assign to it, like so `*p = 4;`. Now you can also assign to `p` itself, but that is a bit different. `p` **is** the identifier of an object. While `*p` refers to some other object (an `int`) without naming it directly, by a result of a less simple expression.

It's a subtle difference, and yet the deduction rules for `decltype` try to emphasize and preserve it as follows ([[dcl.type.simple]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.simple#4)):

> For an expression e, the type denoted by decltype(e) is defined as
>   follows:
>
> - otherwise, if e is an unparenthesized id-expression [...], decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e.
> - otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e;

Comment: Can you elaborate `Not just any old int, it actually gives an lvalue. You can assign to it, like so *p = 4`. I didn't get this part.

Comment: @vcx34178 - When you dereference a pointer you *name* an object. Thus allowing you to assign to it, for instance, like `*p = 3;`. It's different than the result of `int i = 3; i + 3`, for example, which is not an lvalue. It doesn't name an object, it just has value.

Comment: `p` is also an lvalue, but the OP's `decltype(p)` does not produce `int *&`, it just produces `int *`. I think it would be good to mention why in your answer.

Comment: @hvd - Added the bullet. And tried to give some insight.